# undefined in string form before post data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I send data via POST request to NodeJS server.

```
if(req.method === "POST") {
    let body;

    req.on("data", (chunk) => {
        body += chunk.toString();
    });

    req.on("end", () => {
        console.log(body);
        res.end("OK");
    });
}
```

The console outputs data, but also `undefined` in string form.

```
<input type="text" name="target-url" value="asd">
```

The output is:

```
undefinedtarget-url=asd
```

I can write function which removes it, but I think it is way how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your variable like this `let body = ''`.